# BibLaTeX automatic capitalization of pubstate in entrytype thesis?

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliography entry of type `thesis`, with `institution` and `pubstate` given. In the citation, this results in a dot after the institution, followed by uncapitalized version of `pubstate`.

I would like to have the `pubstate` autocapitalized in this case (as I would like to keep on giving it lowercase in the bibliography file).

As a side question or alternative: How could I make the institution commence in a comma instead of a dot, followed then by the `pubstate`?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@thesis{Clark,
    author = {Shirin Clark},
    title = {My thesis title },
    year = {2016},
    institution = {New York University},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    pubstate = {unpublished}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{Clark}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `pubstate = {\autocap{u}npublished}` do what you want?

Comment: Alternatively `\DeclareFieldFormat{pubstate}{\MakeCapital{#1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably

```
pubstate = {\autocap{u}npublished}
```

---

But you can also use the localisation module with

```
\NewBibliographyString{unpublished}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{unpublished = {unpublished}}
```

In that case you can translate "unpublished" into other languages while still having only `unpubslished` in the `pubstate` field. (`biblatex` already knows the values `inpreparation`, `submitted`, `forthcoming`, `inpress`, `prepublished`.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{Clark,
    author = {Shirin Clark},
    title = {My thesis title},
    year = {2016},
    institution = {New York University},
    location = {New York, NY, USA},
    pubstate = {unpublished},
}
\end{filecontents}

\NewBibliographyString{unpublished}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{unpublished = {unpublished}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Clark}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The longer solution (declaring a new bibliography string) is what I was looking for. I didn't know "unpublished" was no such pre-declared string. In case of "inpress", it works out of the box (it gets transformed to "in press" and capitalized as appropriate).